# Change value of one Mysql variable when subtracting two others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Im not quit sure how to word this. I have a database that stores data pertaining to customers invoices. In the database is the customers "Date"(data of procedure) their "Due_Date"(date their payment is due) and "Aging"(which is how many days over due they are)

What im looking to do is take their "Due_Date" and subtract it by the current date, that then changes their aging value. I would like this to be done when a "refresh" button is pressed because im adding the database to a table with php.

**Home.php**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="RefreshBtn">Refresh</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive sortable" id="MyTable">
                        <tr class="header">
                            <td>id</td>
                            <td>Rep</td>
                            <td>Date</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>P_O</td>
                            <td>Due Date</td>
                            <td>Terms</td>
                            <td>Aging</td>
                            <td>Open Balance</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                                $className ="";
                                if ($row['Aging'] >= 45)
                                {
                                    $className="danger";
                                }
                                else if($row['Aging'] >= 25 && $row['Aging'] <= 44)
                                {
                                    $className="warning";
                                }

                                echo "<tr class='$className'>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Rep']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['P_O']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Due_Date']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Terms']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Aging']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Open_Balance']."</td>";
                                echo "<td><a href='deletepage.php?id=" .$row['id']. "' value='" .$row['id']. "' class='btn btn-success'> Paid</a></td>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

How would i go about accomplishing this? I'm stuck and i haven't even begun.

Comment: Hi again. If you can echo your `$query` that populates the `$row` value, its much easier to handle from there. That way you wouldnt even need to refresh, it would be correct every time the page loads.

Comment: @Octopi hello there, the problem is the "aging" value is a hard number in the database as it stands(nothing is controling its value) how do i go about creating some sort of function that would subtract the current date by the .$row['Due_Date'] and change the value of .$row['Aging'] for ALL ROWS?

Comment: You'd ignore it and replace it with a comparison with `due_date` field with `now()` in mysql, if its feasible of course. You wouldn't depend on a user to update how overdue something is, its just overdue. How many other places in your application does `aging` appear?

Comment: @Octopi this one php file is all. When it builds the table. How would i go about achieving what your talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not go through all this trouble when this is a calculated field that does not even need to be stored.

Why not completely removing the Aging field from the database, and let its value be calculated by a query (notice the DATEDIFF):

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, rep, Date, Name, P_O, Due_Date, " .
   "Terms, GREATEST(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date), 0) AS Aging, " .
   "Open_Balance from Book1");
```

This way, whenever the page is refreshed, the SQL makes the calculation in real-time, giving you the Aging value without any need to update.

If you need the Aging field for more processing in the database, then consider making a database view with this Aging expression included.

Comment: I like this a lot acutally, how would i go about integrating this into my current home.php page?

Comment: You must have somewhere a line that says $query = "SELECT ...". That is the only line you need to change, replacing "Aging" with "DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Due_Date) as Aging". All the rest of the code that you have posted can stay.

Comment: this is what i put in the stead of "Aging" echo "<td>".$row['DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Due_Date) as Aging']"</td>"; HOWEVER it is giving me an error under the "</td>" saying unexpected CONSTANT ENCAPSED STRING

Comment: No, no, that is not what I said. You need to find the line higher up in your code, the part you have not posted, where it DEFINES the $query variable.

Comment: ah okay i see what your saying it was `$query = mysql_query("select * from Book1");`  I CHANGED IT TO `$query = "SELECT id, rep, Date, Name, P_O, Due_Date, Terms, DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date) AS Aging, Open_Balance";` HOWEVER now it is giving me an error at line = `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))`

Comment: You need to finish the query by adding " from Book1" at the end again. That part you should not remove of course. So: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, rep, Date, Name, P_O, Due_Date, Terms, DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date) AS Aging, Open_Balance from Book1");`

Comment: `$query = "SELECT id, rep, Date, Name, P_O, Due_Date, Terms, DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date) as Aging, Open_Balance from Book1";` Im still getting the error

Comment: I just noticed you also deleted the call to myslq_query... You need to keep that. I edited my last comment

Comment: perfect it worked :) however im now getting Negative numbers if their due_date isnt till the future? any quick fixes for this?

Comment: I have updated my main answer: if you want records with a future due date to have an Aging value of zero instead of negative, include the GREATEST( ... , 0) function in the SQL. Please accept my answer if you think it was helpful. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here would be to use the MySQL [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to work out the ageing dynamically.

Your query would then look some thing like (assuming your table is called `Invoices`):

```
    SELECT id, 
           Rep, 
           Date, 
           Name, 
           P_O, 
           Due_Date, 
           Terms, 
           DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date) AS Aging, 
           Open_Balance
    FROM Invoices;
```

If you're going to want to refer to the `Aging` value in numerous queries I'd be inclined to create a [View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) in your database with the Aging logic in, as it would probably make things more maintainable and easier to edit etc.

Comment: this makes sense but exactly where do i put this?

Comment: Wherever you are writing your `$query` variable in your PHP code

Comment: i change it to `$query = "SELECT id, rep, Date, Name, P_O, Due_Date, Terms, DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date) as Aging, Open_Balance FROM Book1";` HOWEVER it is now giving me an error at line= `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))`